# How do i fix this navbar Issue in my website?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

How do I fix This navbar issue in my website. If you Check This link (http://ibrahim.techrms.com/), You will find that the navbar Buttons are squished together in the home page. The same code is in the pages "About us" and "Contact us". But the navbar in the "About us" and "Contact us" pages are not squished together.

This is the code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tecmarks</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tecmarks.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: darkgrey;
 color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
</style>
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top" style="background-color: lightgrey">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://tecmarks.com/"><img src="images/logo (1).png"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home
              </a>
        </li>
       <li class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Company</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="about.html">About us</a>
  </div>
</li>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Our Solutions</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" class="disabled">Human Resources & Payroll</a>
    <a href="#" class="disabled">Time Attendance</a>
    <a href="#" class="disabled">Time Sheet Managment</a>
    <a href="#" class="disabled">Website Design & Development</a>
    <a href="#" class="disabled">Domain & Hosting</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Our websites</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="http://tecmarks.com/">Tecmarks</a>
    <a href="index.html">ibrahim.techrms</a>
    <a href="http://feuger.com/">Feuger</a>
  </div>
</div>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="contact-us.html">Contact us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but it wasn't a problem the thing was that is was a responsive navbar and it joins together in smaller views in mobiles and all it will become a dropdown button.
Sorry about the question. If you liked the question please vote for it :)
I only have one badge and 11 points.If you liked my website you can enable notifications and I'll let you know if i changed it or not. If you want you could tell me how my website looks like from your point of view. If you didn't like it then you can tell me what changes I Should do in the website then I'll let you know when I edited the website. I am a beginner in making websites This is a website that I am making for a company,Tecmarks.com